# Opencv installation codeblocks

Tags: windows, opencv, cmake, codeblocks

I'm trying to install opencv on windows10 system and code blocks IDE, while rebuilding opencv with codeblocks i got the following errors :

C:\Desktop\opencv\opencv\sources\modules\contrib\src\chamfermatching.cpp|969|error: the compiler can assume that the address of 'annotate_img' will never be NULL [-Werror=address]|

and:

Comment: See that OpenCV bugreport: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6195

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get source from opencv github master branch. Because I download opencv 4.3.0 and it doesn't have `contrib` folder. If you don't need additional functions from `contrib`, I suggest that you download from here: https://opencv.org/releases/.

If you need those functions, here is my two cents. From the [bug report](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6195). The bug is from `if (&annotate_img!=NULL) {`, it is a common check for pointer, but `annotate_img` is a reference, its address is never NULL. This is not a critical error, you can directly change the source code like [this](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/opencv/blob/f24/f/opencv-2.4.12.3-gcc6.patch) and see if it helps.